# Unable to find Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication on NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, nuget-package, azure-keyvault

I am using ASP.NET Core framework to build an API with Azure Key Vault. I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://anthonychu.ca/post/secrets-aspnet-core-key-vault-msi/) but I am not able to find **Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication** in the NuGet packages.

[image]

The tutorial is targeted for ASP.Net Core framework and used AzureServiceTokenProvider() from the AppAuthentication package.

[image]

Comment: Include pre-release?

Comment: @juunas yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a prerelease nuget package so you should check "Include prerelease" option before searching.

Answer (score 5):

The 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication' has been deprecated and replaced by Azure.Identity.

Answer (score 1):

try this link

[Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication)

maybe because it is preview

Answer (score 0):

For new Azure application development, it is strongly recommended to use `Azara.Identity` and the new Azure client SDKs. For existing application that uses `AppAuthentication`, the preferred path is to migrate the package and use the new Azure client SDKs.  The package `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` has been deprecate and no longer supported.

Please read the documentation here for further details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/app-auth-migration?view=azure-dotnet